# Struggling with Datetime Parsing

Tags: clickhouse

Can I using some internal ch functions to convert this datetime format 5/11/2021 13:10:25 to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ?
I'm quite struggling while find it out.
I've tried following:
replaceRegexpOne(toString(START_TIME), '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', '(\2)-(\1)-(\3)')

But got:

RROR: garbage after DateTime: "375291300"
ERROR: DateTime must be in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss or NNNNNNNNNN (unix timestamp, exactly 10 digits) format.

: (at row 1)
, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, int, bool) @ 0x8b770fa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::throwAtAssertionFailed(char const*, DB::ReadBuffer&) @ 0x8bcd437 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. ? @ 0x105329db in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::CSVRowInputFormat::readRow(std::__1::vector<COW<DB::IColumn>::mutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::allocator<COW<DB::IColumn>::mutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > >&, DB::RowReadExtension&) @ 0x10532b2e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::IRowInputFormat::generate() @ 0x1051ccc8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::ISource::tryGenerate() @ 0x104a97d5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::ISource::work() @ 0x104a93ba in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ParallelParsingInputFormat::InternalParser::getChunk() @ 0x10567dde in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ParallelParsingInputFormat::parserThreadFunction(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroupStatus>, unsigned long) @ 0x1056737e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. ThreadPoolImpl::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0x8bb9ed8 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl::scheduleImpl(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional)::'lambda1'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl::scheduleImpl(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional)::'lambda1'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0x8bbb89f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ThreadPoolImplstd::__1::thread::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x8bb741f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ? @ 0x8bba943 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. start_thread @ 0x9609 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
14. clone @ 0x122293 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
    (version 21.6.6.51 (official build))
    (I can't show whole stack trace because of private data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetimebesteffort

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetimebesteffortUS

```
SELECT parseDateTimeBestEffort('5/11/2021 13:10:25')


┌─parseDateTimeBestEffort('5/11/2021 13:10:25')─┐
│                           2021-11-05 13:10:25 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-date_time_input_format

You can set `date_time_input_format=best_effort` in a session, query or user's profile. It will allow to parse text formats CSV/TSV/JSON*,...

Comment: thanks! I've added date_time_input_format=best_effort + specified it parseDateTimeBestEffort(toString(START_TIME)) into insert query and insert was succesful!